# Comparing two columns in Business Objects

Tags: webi

I need to compare two columns from two queries and put the result into a 3rd column.

Column 1 is the master sheet (Query 1) where the main ID number list is.

Column 2 on another Query (Query 2) are the ID numbers I want to compare to column 1 and return a "Yes" result in column 3 if the same ID is present on Column 2 (Query 2) without removing the rows where there are no results.

I can manage to get the report to filter column one to match the list on column 2 using the following simple formula.

```
=if[dimension1]=[dimesnion2]Then "Yes" else " "
```

I need all the data to remain unfiltered on Query 1 and just a `Yes` or a blank in column 3.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and wlcome to SO. In order to help people better understand your problem, it would be useful if you added a minimal code example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.